# Cannot resolve symbol 'StringEntity'

Tags: java, android, apache, android-studio

For some reason, my Android Studio can't find the StringEntity class. It seems that I'm missing apache classes, are they something I need to install? I was under the assumption that they came with Android studio...

Thanks!

Comment: Apache HttpClient was removed in Android 6.0 - see here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: Implemented the legacy library, works now :D Ty